# Convert a 240 hot tub outlet to 120

Tags: hot-tub

We have a 240 outlet on our patio that was used for a hot tub. I'd like to convert it to 120, have an outlet there on the house then also run a line to install an outlet on our new pergola. Can this be done?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the hot tub gone?  Do you *only* want to power these outlets from here?

Comment: The hot tub is gone. I was figuring this would be the simplest place to connect a 120 line to the pergola.

Comment: Or this? [How can I convert 240 to 120 for hot tub downsizing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/184127/need-to-convert-220-to-110-for-hot-tub-downsizing)

Answer (score 14):

Your panel seems confused as to whether it takes Eaton BR breakers or GE breakers.  Despite them seeming to fit, they're not actually compatible.

- GE panels take GE breakers.
- Westinghouse (Challenger), BRyant, and Eaton (Cutler Hammer) panels take Eaton BR.

I would replace the GE 50A breaker with the appropriate 20A 2-pole breaker.

Then use #12 wire to connect your local receptacle to one of the hot pins and neutral of that 50A GFCI breaker in the disconnect.

For your pergola run, also use #12 wire and connect it to the other hot pin and neutral on that 50A GFCI breaker in the disconnect.

It's fine for the breakers to disagree *in value* - you have a 20A in series with a 50A, so that will act like a 20A breaker.  The breakers are splitting their jobs.

The 50A breaker is providing GFCI protection that you already paid for, and the plain 20A breaker (dirt cheap) is providing overload protection.   If you would rather use #14 wire to the pergola, use a 15A breaker. Use plain outlets and label them "GFCI Protected".

Comment: @isherwood It's HNQ :)